# Generic Approval Matrix for MS Dynamics CRM

Tags: generics, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

Is there any way to create a generic approval matrix in MS Dynamics CRM, which allow user or team to approve a request up to N level and will auto assign approval request to Next Level user or team?

Answer (score 2):

One thought would be to create a business process, or set of business processes, but since you want it to be generic, I doubt this approach will provide the flexibility you're looking for.

So, you might want to look at an approach that would require three custom entities.

1. Approval Stage - would hold the user or team, and their order in the sequence.
2. Approval Sequence - would parent multiple approval stages to make them into a set.
3. Approval Process - a linking entity to associate an Approval Sequence to the record you're approving. This would create an N:N relationship so that multiple records could be going through the same Approval Sequence at the same time.

Then you'll need custom code (workflow or plugin) that triggers initially to set the first user/team to approve. Then when each next user approves it would look into the Approval Process's Approval Sequence to get the next user/team to assign it to.